# run one where clause condition on the base of parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

i have ha query like this

```
Select * from table1 
where col1 = true or col2 = false or 
case when @param <> 2 then col3 = col4 end
```

last condition in where is throwing an error

```
 Incorrect syntax near '<'
```

Comment: could you please try using != instead  of <>

Comment: You can refer this answer if you really want to use `case` in `where` clause
https://stackoverflow.com/a/206500/4923740

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44875190/411860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ( COL1='TRUE' OR COL2='FALSE' 
OR (@PARAM<>2 AND COL3=COL4) )
```

Comment: `(@PARAM<>2 AND COL3=COL4) )` gud one bro . but can't we handle this with case statement  as well as you told me previous before ..??

Comment: You can handle with `CASE` too. Case expression won't use indexes exist on that column. But the above approach will use indexes.       If there is no index available on those columns both approaches will give same performance. @Mahesh.K

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a `CASE` expression to control execution flow in SQL. `CASE` is an *expression* that simply returns a *scalar* value.

You can use the following predicates instead:

```
((@param <> 2 AND col3 = col4) OR (@param = 2))
```

So, the `WHERE` clause of your query will look like:

```
WHERE (col1 = true) OR (col2 = false) OR ((@param <> 2 AND col3 = col4) OR (@param = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `case` in question is intended to express predicate "when  @param <> 2 then col3 = col4  must hold". I also assume for simplicity no column is nullable. This quite formally translates into `!(@param <> 2) OR col3 = col4` which is equivalent to  `@param = 2 OR col3 = col4`

```
Select * from table1 
where col1 = 'true' or col2 = 'false' or 
@param = 2 OR col3 = col4
```